# how to get the HTML Table border at Down

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

i am trying to add the Table in the HTML using ionic Platfrom, 
the HTML for the  Table shows below,

the HTML and CSS code is been added below ,

*the code starts here*

```
<strong>Current Production Order No:</strong>

      <div class="row text">
          <div class="col">Rolled :</div> 
        <div class="col">103.7</div>
      </div>

      <div class="row text">
        <div class="col">To be rolled: </div> 
      <div class="col">145</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text">
      <div class="col">Yield:</div> 
    <div class="col">0.124</div>
    </div><br>

 <strong>Current Number of Billets</strong>

      <div class="row text">
          <div class="col">C Hook:</div> 
        <div class="col">1452</div>
      </div>

      <div class="row text">
        <div class="col">Conveyor: </div> 
      <div class="col">C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text">
      <div class="col"> Mill:</div> 
    <div class="col">5</div>
    </div> 
    <div class="row text">
        <div class="col">Furnace:</div> 
      <div class="col">1245</div>
      </div> 
<br>
 <strong>Last Production Order No:</strong>

      <div class="row text">
          <div class="col">Rolled:</div>  
            <div class="col">In Progress</div>

      </div>

      <div class="row text">
        <div class="col">Cobbled: </div> 
      <div class="col">Yes</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text">
      <div class="col"> Yield:</div> 
    <div class="col">0.124</div>
    </div>
```

the Css shows Below

```
                  .text{
                      text-align: left;
                      }
                  .logo{
                    width: 50px;
                    height: 20px;

                    }
                   .footer{
                     text-align: center;
                    }
               .col {
                border: solid 1px rgb(219, 217, 217);
               border-bottom-style: solid 1px rgb(219, 217, 217);

               }
               .col:last-child .col {
                border-right: solid 1px rgb(219, 217, 217);
                 border: solid 1px rgb(219, 217, 217);
               }
               .row:last-child .col {
                 border-bottom: solid 1px rgb(219, 217, 217);
                  border: solid 1px rgb(219, 217, 217);
               }
             p {
                 margin-bottom: 8em;
            }
```

i need the Below image to looks good,
the Line below is need to shown with border,,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nq0Nd.jpg)

thanks in advance......

Comment: As per your code border is coming. It might be an issue with div overlapping or overflow.

Comment: can you try that without br tag

Answer (score 0):

Initially you want to make parent as table...and children(lol) as table-cell ...thn if you want equal width thn give width as above .....use that css code and please inform if u have any doubt or bug let me know !!!!!!

```
.row{
    display:table;
    width:20%;
}

.col{
    display:table-cell;
    width:68px !important;
}
```